# UICollectionView Prefetch Data Source in iOS 10?

Tags: swift3, ios10, xcode8

What is the purpose of `prefetchDataSources` introduced in iOS 10?

I just ran a project in XCode 8 GM Seed and started getting errors:

```
MessagesExtension[17902:1238603] *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:], /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-3599.6/UICollectionView.m:2161
```

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> UICollectionView gains a new property this year called
>   prefetchDataSource. Just like the existing delegate and dataSource
>   properties, we can simply set it to some object that implements the new
>   UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching protocol.

**This protocol is brand new in iOS 10, and requires we implement just one new function:**

```
public func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])
```

> When this function is called, we can examine the indexPaths array
>   we're passed in to know which cells are "coming up soon" and thus
>   which cells we should probably begin loading the data for.

For detail understanding with example refer link
[UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching](https://littlebitesofcocoa.com/242-pre-loading-images-with-uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching)

Answer (score 4):

i was had the same problem after updating from xcode 8 to 8.1. 
I could solve it deleting  the (Outlets reference) from the main.storyboard.

[image: Outtles references]

This for every CollectionView that i had in the storyboard. Also leave my ViewController just like that:

[image: Class UIviewcontroller]

Class (YourViewControllerName): (YourViewControllerType) , UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate{

}

Then i can build and run my App

However, if you need use (UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching) i recomment you that delete the current  UICollectionView, later create a new UICollectioView. just like that you can use UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching after updateing xcode or swift

Answer (score 1):

Implement protocol **"UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching"** in you ViewController as

**class ViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {**

Set following delegates to your collection view in storyboard (see the attached image) 
or programmatically

In **ViewController's** *viewDidLoad* method

collectionView.delegate = self

collectionView.dataSource = self

collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self

Refer this example - https://github.com/Be-With-Viresh/CollectionViewWithPrefetch

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add protocol "UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching"
And then use below functions.

1. `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])`
2. `collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cancelPrefetchingForItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath])`

For detail refer Link: https://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2016/06/collection-view-updates-in-ios10/