# Maintain collectionview speed after reloading data in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am implementing a chat app using UICollectionView. Initially I fetch only 100 messages. As the user scrolls, I fetch some more messages and then reload the collection view. To maintain the scroll position I set the content offset but scrolling gets stopped. How to maintain the scrolling speed after reloading the UICollectionView so user doesn't feel jerk?

Comment: Just don't reload collection view. When it's scrolled make request for new data and load it lazily to the cells.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the prefetchDataSource that was introduced in iOS10.

[UICollectionView Prefetch Data Source in iOS 10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39430231/uicollectionview-prefetch-data-source-in-ios-10)

Comment: prefetching data is not the issue. it is working fine. only problem is , after reloading the collectionView , scrolling gets stopped so user feel jerk.

Answer (score 0):

There're several approaches to handle this.

1. You don't use `reloadData()` but rather `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:`, that way you don't have rebuild the whole table and only build the items you need.
2. You load additional data when use hits a specific point your collection view. In a `willDisplayCell` method you can check if `indexPath` of a cell is getting close to the last index in your data source and load additional rows. In the moment user will scroll to the last item, all the stuff will be already there so you don't have worry.

In my experience the best way is to use both of this approaches combined. Because in general using `reloadData()` every now and then could be very resourceful depending on your cell layouts.